# Motivation behind Primary Decomposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, big-picture

I am reading Atiyah's Commutative Algebra chapter on Primary Decomposition. I understand the proofs but I have no intuition as to

- How did one come up with definition of a primary ideal $q$ as

> $xy \in q \Rightarrow$ either $x \in q$ or $y^n \in q$ for some $n>0$

- Why we know that this decomposition is a "nice" one.

> Perhaps there are other decompositions, that satisfies some uniqueness properties. What is so special/"canonical" about this hecomposition?

- What properties of primary decomposition are "important" - what are the consequences?

> I am confused as to what properties yields more important results. I have skipped ahead and look at some corollaries; some results can also be proven  with out the theory primary decomposition.

---

What I am look here is a more detailed motivation/intuition. Rather than "prime decomposition in the ideals". Feel free to close this post if it is too broad.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z$ consider the principal ideals $\{ k \cdot x \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$ for $x$ prime or non-prime. The definition at hand is an abstraction of that and one that proved useful. (Keep in mind: Mathematical definitions are subject to evolution after all.)

Comment: I find it hard to have any intuition for results in commutative algebra without the corresponding [view towards algebraic geometry](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387942681). Do you have any background in algebraic geometry? I feel that most of your questions are easily answered if you do, and would require some explanation (from my perspective) if you do not.

Comment: I have no background in algebraic geometry, I am mostly doing exercises from A&M. Thanks, I should check out this book.

Comment: @Jesko Hüttenhain I have a background in Algebraic Geometry and have the same question, what made people search for primary decomposition of ideals in polynomial rings? It corresponds to irreducible components of varieties, but why do we care about those components?